# EF Core Multiple migration sets

Tags: .net-core, entity-framework-core

I'm currently working on a .Net Core app using EF Core Code First Migrations. I'm jumping between Windows and OS X to do my development (Windows at home, Mac on the go) and I'm trying to figure out how I can use database migrations for SQL Server when I am on Windows and SQLite when on my Mac.

Is it possible to maintain two sets of migrations and select which set to apply (without needing to specify each migration individually)? Or would I need to create separate .Net Core applications/assemblies and specify the `--assembly` option for the `dotnet ef database update` command?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have two options:

1. Use two sets of Migrations
2. Manually edit the migrations to be provider-agnostic

### Multiple sets

Each set needs to be in its own assembly. To get started, generate the first migration and move it into a new project. You would configure the migrations assembly when you configured the provider.

```cs
optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer(
    mssqlConnectionString
    , x => x.MigrationsAssembly("MyApp.Migrations.SqlServer"));
//optionsBuilder.UseSqlite(
//    sqliteConnectionString,
//    x => x.MigrationsAssembly("MyApp.Migrations.Sqlite"));
```

I have [a sample](https://github.com/bricelam/Sample-SplitMigrations) that puts migrations in their own assembly that you might also want to use as a reference.

### Provider-agnostic

To make the migrations provider-agnostic, merge what each provider would generate. For example, the following has annotations for both SQL Server and SQLite.

```cs
migrationBuilder.CreateTable(
    name: "People",
    columns: table => new
    {
        Id = table.Column<int>(nullable: false)
            .Annotation("Sqlite:Autoincrement", true)
            .Annotation("SqlServer:ValueGenerationStrategy",
                SqlServerValueGenerationStrategy.IdentityColumn)
    },
    constraints: table =>
    {
        table.PrimaryKey("PK_People", x => x.Id);
    });
```

Comment: That's super helpful! It sounds like, either way there is some type of manual editing going on then? Whether it be moving migrations to another assembly, or adding the needed data to the migration directly; is that correct?

Comment: Yes. We've played with the idea of adding first-class support for using Migrations with multi-provider models (see [#1825](https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFramework/issues/1825)), but the cost is very high. For now, we just strive to enable you do do it manually.

Comment: When I run the `dotnet ef migrations add Sample --project ..\MyApp.Migrations` I get `Unrecognized option --project`. Also noticed [this](https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFramework/issues/6827) on Github. Does this make the sample repo out-of-date since it's marked "closed-wont-fix"?

Comment: @Bwolfing GitHub issue is unrelated (it's about `--project-dir`). Make sure you're using 1.0.0 or 1.1.0 RTM packages. See if `--help` works.

Comment: Was able to figure it out by changing Tools to 1.0.0 (as suggested) and upgraded from `project.json` to .Net Core 1.1's `.csproj` format

Comment: I initially thought that migrations are added to ease the db script management, however when it comes to multiple providers it made so difficult. I think MS should release such all functionalities with limitations.  now I'm in a situation where I have spend most time and MS decided not supporting multiple providers db migrations !!!